# How can I recreate this dirt in grooves effect?

Tags: texturing, ambient-occlusion

I cannot seem to find any tutorials for grunge specifically inside grooves. I have tried methods using the ambient occlusion node but it just ends up looking like rust or imperfections in the metal.
It is specifically the dirt in the grooves of the knurled handle I'm trying to replicate. I don't have substance painter, so I was hoping I could do it procedurally in Blender.

[image]

Comment: You could paint a b&w image with a dirt texture, that you'll use as a factor between 2 shaders

Comment: I'm up for that. Should I create a grunge texture in Photoshop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe mix the *AO* with a *Noise Texture* through a *Mix Color* in *Lighten mode*, plug the *Mix Color* into the *Base Color* and the *Specular* input of the *Principled BSDF*, or use the *Mix Color* as a factor in a *Mix Shader* between 2 different *Principled BSDF*, one being set to create the dirt.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Looks just the solution!